# Does this normal integral have a closed form?

Tags: definite-integrals, normal-distribution, gaussian-integral

I'm interested in the integral:

\begin{equation*}
\int_0^{\infty} x\left(\Phi(x) - 1/2\right)^{n} \varphi(x) \varphi(xt)dx
\end{equation*}
Where $n \ge 1$ is an integer and $t \in [-1, 1]$ is a parameter. $\Phi$ and $\varphi$ are the gaussian CDF and PDFs respectively.

I was thinking that to start with I might expand the binomial term to get the integrals:

\begin{equation*}
\int_0^{\infty} x \Phi(x)^{k} \varphi(x) \varphi(xt)dx
\end{equation*}

I looked in Owen's tables, but this exact integral doesn't seem to be present. If it were I think it would be at index `n111`. Does anyone know if there's a close form solution to either the full integral or even just the monomial terms?